# Error Ogre3D on linux

Tags: linux, ogre3d

I'm beginner in ogre3D and I'm build mi first program in Ogre3D, but when I try to compile the program I get this error:

```sh
In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char,                                                                 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, 
std::allocator<char> const&)'

test.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char,    
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*,   
std::allocator<char> const&)'

test.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char,  
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*,  
std::allocator<char> const&)'
```

And Continue the fix

1. I Compile the program manually:

```sh
gcc test.cpp  -o test.o test
```

And my file test is this:

```c
#include <Ogre.h>

using namespace Ogre;

int main()
{
Root* root= new Root();

if( !root->restoreConfig() )
{
    root->showConfigDialog();
    root->saveConfig();
}
return 0;
}
```

How to fix my problem?

I'm use Debian Wheezy.

The Version Ogre3D: 1.8

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linker error.
Use `pkg-config --libs` to retrieve the correct linker options

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags OGRE) $(pkg-config --libs OGRE) -lboost_system
```

If you have installed OGRE in a nonstandard location (say `/opt/ogre`), you may need to call pkg-config with the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable set:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ogre/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --libs OGRE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a linker error, but not to Ogre3d, but to the STL (Standard Template Library). The reason for this is that you are using **gcc**, when you should be using **g++**. However, I am surprised that you aren't getting linker errors to Ogre as well, and the solution to that is like Thomas suggested (though he also uses "g++" in his example).

Comment: You can also ask these type of questions in #ogre3d on the freenode irc network.